# Curl Command to setup SSL in AEM 6.5

Tags: aem

The `curl` command mentioned in the below official documentation of Adobe works fine for AEM 6.3, however for AEM 6.5 it results in HTTP 500 Error- `NullPointerException`.

```
curl \
  -u user:password \
  -F "keystorePassword=password" \
  -F "keystorePasswordConfirm=password" \
  -F "truststorePassword=password" \
  -F "truststorePasswordConfirm=password" \
  -F "privatekeyFile=@localhostprivate.der" \
  -F "certificateFile=@localhost.crt" \
  -F "httpsHostName=host.example.com" \
  -F "httpsPort=8443" \   
  http://host:port/libs/granite/security/post/sslSetup.html



*ERROR* [POST /lib/granite/security/post/sslSetup.html HTTP/1.1]
com.adobe.granite.security.user.ui.internal.servlets.SSLConfigurationServlet Error while Configuring SSL:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
          at java.util.Hashtable.put (Hashtable.java:460)
          at com.adobe.granite.security.user.ui.internal.servlets.SSLConfigurationServlet.configureSSLConnectionFactory(SSLConfigurationServlet.java:525)
          [com.adobe.granite.security.ui:1.0.58]
          at com.adobe.granite.security.user.ui.internal.servlets.SSLConfigurationServlet.doPost(SSLConfigurationServlet.java:374)
          [com.adobe.granite.security.ui:1.0.58]
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/administering/using/ssl-by-default.html

Looking for suggestion on what should be the command for 6.5 then.

I am working on some automation tasks, due to which I need to setup SSL via command line only and not via the SSL wizard.

When I try manually via the SSL Wizard, its successful, but not working via the above `curl` command.

Comment: Can you please add the `NullPointerException`. That might already point us in the right direction.

Comment: Added the exception . please check.

Comment: Resolved . The attribute need to be httpsHostname not httpsHostName .

Lower case 'n' and not Upper case 'N'

Comment: Can you please create an answer to your question with this info and accept it (answering your own question is allowed).

Comment: Done. Answered. Awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved . The attribute need to be httpsHostname not httpsHostName . Lower case 'n' and not Upper case 'N'